# How do you declare temporary strings for reuse in C?

Tags: c

I have a while loop that takes a user input until the user says quit but i am not sure how to declare the strings properly. If the user only inputs one word, the second variable will stay the same value from the previous loop.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    char user_input[25];
    char var1[25], var2[25];
    while(strcmp(var1, "quit") != 0){
        clear_buffer(user_input);
        fgets(user_input, 30, stdin);
        sscanf(user_input, "%s %s", var1, var2);
        do_stuff(var1, var2);
    }
    printf("%s", "Done\n");
```

Comment: `fgets(user_input, 30` seems wrong considering the buffer is only 25 bytes.

Comment: `var1` is uninitialized when you first enter the loop.

Comment: @DigitalNinja: I think some commands have only one word, in which case the second word should be passed as a zero length string.

Comment: Indeed, if `user_input` only holds 1 word, `var2` will stay untouched and if `user_input` only contains space characters, both `var1` and `var2` will stay untouched.  You should set `var1[0]` and `var2[0]` to `'\0'` before the `sscanf`

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh, thanks... the "quit", didn't notice that.

Comment: `do_stuff` will be called for the `"quit"` command... probably not intended.  move the test after the `sscanf()` and break from the loop if it matches.

Comment: You should test `fgets()` return value, avoiding an infinite loop upon end of file and making `clear_buffer()` useless.

Comment: `printf("%s", "Done\n");` -> `printf("Done\n");`

Comment: *If the user only inputs one word, the second variable will stay the same value from the previous loop.*  is this a requirement or a problem?

Answer (score 5):

> i am not sure how to declare the strings properly

Strings aren't a type. They're a value pattern, and like other values we don't declare them; we assign them (using `strcpy` and other functions, in this case). If you say an `int` stores a multiple of ten, then it ends in 0... If you say an array of `char` stores a string, then it ends at the first `'\0'`. Do you see the pattern yet? We can store multiples of ten in different kinds of integer variables, and likewise for strings we can choose different types of character arrays. Similarly for storing numeric values in `integer` variables, when declaring an array to store a string, you'll want to be sure the array has enough space to store all of the characters for the string plus a `'\0'` at the end.

> If the user only inputs one word, the second variable will stay the same value from the previous loop.

Check the return value of `sscanf`.

For example, when considering `int x = sscanf(user_input, "%s %s", var1, var2);` you may want to be sure the 2 arguments you give `sscanf` are assigned to, in which case you'll be checking that `x == 2`. If you only care about the first argument being assigned, then you'll be happy when `x == 1`, too. However, if `x <= 0` then you can't trust either `var1` or `var2`

Answer (score 2):

Multiple problems

1. You never initialize `var1` but you use `strcmp()`, you need to initialize `var1` before trying to use `strcmp()`, if you want to initialize to an empty string just

   ```
   var1[0] = '\0';
   ```
2. You pass `30` to `fgets()` but `user_input` can only hold `25` characters.

Now to why is the program behaving the way it is, you need to check that `sscanf()` did read both strings, if it doesn't it does not alter the passed parameters.

The `scanf()` function returns the number of specifiers matched by the input, so if

1. `scanf()` returns `0`, it means both parameters are not initialized/modified.
2. `scanf()` returns `1` one of the parameters is initialized/modified.
3. When both were initialized/modified, then it will return `2`, so checking for that would let you know what is going wrong, and you can print the input string to verify that `scanf()` was right, and the input was wrong..

Comment: Heh, correction to your last sentance: if `scanf` doesn't read both strings, it _needs to clear_ the parameter(s).

Answer (score 1):

```
char user_input[50+1];
char var1[25], var2[25];

while(fgets(user_input, sizeof(user_input), stdin)){
    int state = sscanf(user_input, "%24s %24s", var1, var2);
    if(state == 1 && strcmp(var1, "quit") == 0)
        break;
    else if(state == 2)
        do_stuff(var1, var2);
}
```

Comment: Why should `quit now` invoke `do_stuff` and more importantly, why should commands without arguments be ignored?

Comment: If there are two inputs to the input I is considered not want to enable a quit. This is because when you want to stop it there is no need to specify a second argument. also If the two inputs are not it I is considered to be invalid. The reason is because the `do_stuff` requires two arguments.

Comment: The requirements are not clear from the OP's question, to say the least. Your argument on `quit` it debatable.  What about commands without an argument? Just ignoring them seems incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version taking comments into account and protecting `sscanf` arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char user_input[80];
    char var1[25], var2[25];

    while (fgets(user_input, (int)(sizeof user_input), stdin)) {
        *var2 = '\0';
        if (sscanf(user_input, "%24s %24s", var1, var2) > 0) {
            if (!strcmp(var1, "quit"))
                break;
            do_stuff(var1, var2);
        }
    }
    printf("Done\n");
    return 0;
}
```